# Mapbox map not filling ion-content fullscreen

Tags: ionic-framework, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to make my header transparent with

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-toolbar >
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button color="primary"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content fullscreen>
   <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

and in .scss

```
ion-content{
  --ion-background-color: transparent;
}

ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
  --color: white;
}

#map { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

but still the div with id="map" doesn't get fullscreen and I always get this no matter what

[image]

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

html.file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="transparent">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button color="light"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title color="light" text-center>Sign In</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>
</ion-content>
```

css.file

```
ion-content{
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I had already tried it and it doesn't work, I think it is the map div that doesn't go all the way up but I don't know why

Comment: bro i have same page you give the color="transparent" in ion-toolbar tag